# Python .replace() inside double For-loop issues

Tags: python, for-loop

This feels like a really easy solve, but I can't get this to work:

```
def cleaning(recipe):
    #make every element lowercase
    recipe = [str.lower(i) for i in recipe]

    #remove punctuations
    chars = "\\`\'\"*_{}[]%&()>#+-.!$"

    for c in chars:
        for item in recipe:
            if c in item:
                item = item.replace(c,'')

    return recipe
```

If I use this^ function and run this,

```
blah = ['Salt', 'Hot&Sour Sauce']
blah = cleaning(blah)
```

I get:

```
['salt', 'hot&sour sauce']
```

With the character replacement not taking effect. 
Feels like a really elementary issue, can someone point out the quick fix?

thanks!

Comment: You're creating a copy with the `item.replace()` call

Comment: ...And then not overwriting the list element's current value with the copy.

Comment: Do you expect result is `['salt', 'hotsour sauce']`?

Comment: [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) is the right tool for the job, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for c in chars:
    for item in recipe:
        if c in item:
            item = item.replace(c,'')
```

You're assigning a new string to the `item` reference, but that doesn't change the value in the `list`. Either iterate through indices (e.g. `for i in range(len(recipe))... recipe[i] = new_string`) or use a different strategy, possibly one that doesn't involve nested loops.

```
>>> r = ['Salt', 'Hot&Sour Sauce']
```

You could use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> def cleaning(recipe):
...     return list(map(lambda item: re.sub(r'''[\\`'"*_{}\[\]%&()>#+-.!$]*''', '', item.lower()), recipe))
...
>>> cleaning(r)
['salt', 'hotsour sauce']
```

Or a filter:

```
>>> def cleaning(recipe):
...     return [''.join(filter(lambda i: i not in "\\`\'\"*_{}[]%&()>#+-.!$", item.lower())) for item in recipe]
...
>>> cleaning(r)
['salt', 'hotsour sauce']
```

Answer (score 1):

you are updating item, but not updating the list containing item

```
chars = "\\`\'\"*_{}[]%&()>#+-.!$"

recipe = ['Salt', 'Hot&Sour Sauce']
print(recipe)
for c in chars:
    for i, item in enumerate(recipe):
        if c in item:
            item = item.replace(c,'')
            recipe[i] = item # here the list is updated.

print(recipe)

['Salt', 'Hot&Sour Sauce']
['Salt', 'HotSour Sauce']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually mutate the list with out explicitly assigning to the entry in the list. In other words performing `item = item.replace(c,'')` will do nothing to `recipe`.

You can modify the list to work by enumerating but you may want to consider mapping or list comprehension as you did with converting `recipe` to lower case. In this case you can use a special case of `str.translate` where the `table` parameter is `None` and the `deletechars` parameter is punctuation.

You can rewrite your function now in terms of maps or list comprehensions. For example:

```
def cleaning(recipe):
    punc = "\\`\'\"*_{}[]%&()>#+-.!$"
    rm_punc = lambda s: str.translate(s.lower(), None, punc) #Special case of str.translate.
    return map(rm_punc, recipe) #Remove the punctuation.

blah = ['Salt', 'Hot&Sour Sauce']
blah = cleaning(blah)

print blah
```

Prints:

```
['salt', 'hotsour sauce']
```

Comment: You can get rid of the second `map` by doing the `translate` directly on `s.lower()`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Updated. Thanks for catching that.